# yesterday evening I send out 0.97 BTC. I checked transaction and It says : " lock time 459355"

Tags: locktime

are my coins lost ? please help

It says Lock Time: 459355

and still unconfirmed since yesterday

Answer (score 1):

No, your coins are not lost. Either they get confirmed and become available to the recipient, or they are unspent and remain yours.

All transactions created with Bitcoin Core (and maybe also other wallets) set their transaction to be confirmed only with the next block at the earliest. This is done to [discourage fee-sniping](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/48384/5406).

In your case I assume that the current block was `459354`, so the transaction was created locked to the next block `459355`. Since we're currently at block `459475`, the delay of confirmation for your transaction would not be related to the locktime.

For more information please see [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/9046/5406).

Comment: thanks for the answer! but how long do i have to wait ?

Comment: @KonstantinHa: My pleasure. Welcome to Bitcoin.StackExchange by the way. If you're curious to learn how our site works, please check out our [tour]. If the question has been answered to your satisfaction, you may mark this answer as accepted. :)